# Installing v8-profiler using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, v8

While trying

```
npm install -g v8-profiler
```

I'm hitting the below errors:

```
..\graph_node.cc(99): error C2039: 'GetRetainersCount' : is not a member of 'v8::HeapGraphNode' [C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\v8
-profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\username\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(249) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
..\graph_node.cc(132): error C2039: 'GetRetainedSize' : is not a member of 'v8::HeapGraphNode' [C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\v8-
profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\username\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(249) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
..\graph_node.cc(154): error C2039: 'GetRetainer' : is not a member of 'v8::HeapGraphNode' [C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\v8-prof
iler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\username\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(249) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
..\graph_node.cc(162): error C2039: 'GetDominatorNode' : is not a member of 'v8::HeapGraphNode' [C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\v8
-profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\username\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(249) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
  profiler.cc
```

Looks like a compilation issue. What might be wrong ?
My system has :

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Windows SDK 7.1 Note: If you get error on installation, maybe this
   link will help you.
3. Visual Studio 2010 SP1
4. Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1
5. Python 2.7

As mentioned in : https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Setup

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same issue.  It looks like [NodeFly's fork of `v8-profiler`](https://npmjs.org/package/nodefly-v8-profiler) contains the fix that Sean described, so I installed that version instead:

```
npm install nodefly-v8-profiler
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler/issues/16#issuecomment-9099768) on GitHub, some APIs were removed from V8, and v8-profiler hasn't been updated.

> It was V8 problem.
>   v8-profiler uses some V8 API's, but those API's are eliminated from V8 in version 3.11.5.
>
> ...
>
> In order to use v8-profiler, simplest way is to remove the following
>   methods and SetAccessor call inside constructor from graph_node.cc and
>   rebuild v8-profiler.
>
> - GraphNode::GetRetainersCount
> - GraphNode::GetRetainedSize
> - GraphNode::GetRetainer
> - GraphNode::GetDominator
>
> But of course, if you do this, you can't see anymore dominator and retainer informations.